# Set constructor notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is it bad form to place two functions on the left part of a set constructor, e.g., $S = \{i^2, i^3\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ to mean the set containing both squared and cubed natural numbers? Should I write $S = \{i^2\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{i^3\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second expression. The first makes one think of a set of tuples, $\{(i^2,\,i^3)|i\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.